Save rotting links by Google link shortener
I have rececently found a goo.gl link in a comment (here: Searching an element in a sorted array) and when followed, the link displayed a warning:

This link will no longer work in the near future
goo.gl links will no longer function after August 25th, 2025. Visit our blog post for more information about the goo.gl links shutdown.

I posted a valid target link there (Searching an element in a sorted array), but possibly there are more such cases in CodeReview SE.
Is there any method to find such links and replace them with actual destination URLs without manual searching, browsing and editing?

Related on the Main Meta: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/401612/196432

goo.gl links in posts can be found with a search for url:"//goo.gl/", but that does not help for comments.

You can search comments using SEDE. Here is a list of all goo.gl links on Code Review.

Is there any method to find such links and replace them with actual destination URLs without manual searching, browsing and editing?

To "replace" the links requires manual intervention. To do so in-place requires manual intervention from a moderator.
If you'd like to compile a list of replacements I'd be happy to edit the links (if possible due to the character limit).
Here are example formats:
https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/4223/searching-an-element-in-a-sorted-array#comment179059_4223
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity

https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/159150/mass-and-length-calculator-using-perl-6-custom-operator/163644#comment311426_163644
https://goo.gl/lDeFIq
https://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=1186215

If you come across any comments with goo.gl links which are "no longer needed" then feel free to flag the comments.

https://maps.app.goo.gl, https://photos.app.goo.gl, https://images.app.goo.gl continue to function (e.g. here). You can search for //goo.gl/ to avoid these false positives.
